What are spinning black holes orbiting?
I have seen depictions of spinning black holes with the "singularity" spinning around a center of rotation in a flat plane, or moving around an imaginary sphere. Is there anything in the centre or was that poor visualization on the artist's side?


Seen where and in what context? Do you mean a Ring singularity?

see the related video, the answer and animation

I thought the math says the ring singularity is a portal to another universe

Spinning black holes are fun to ponder, but they don’t exist. What exists is spinning collapsed stars, but they aren’t described by Kerr’s metric and don’t have singularities inside.

There isn't anything in particular in the center. The black hole isn't orbiting, it is spinning (by which I mean it is rotating in and of itself). It is similar to how the Earth or a spinning top rotates about its axis: it isn't orbiting anything, just spinning.
